# How to do two separate counts by group by with different WHERE statements in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two separate queries that only differ in the "WHERE" statement:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from created_at),'-', extract(year from created_at)) AS "Month", 
count(email) AS "Total AB Signups"
from users
where is_accountant='t'
group by 1,extract(month from created_at),extract(year from created_at)
order by extract(year from created_at),extract(month from created_at);
```

Then:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from created_at),'-', extract(year from created_at)) AS "Month", 
count(email) AS "Total AB Signups"
from users
where is_accountant='f'
group by 1,extract(month from created_at),extract(year from created_at)
order by extract(year from created_at),extract(month from created_at);
```

How would I merge this into one table that looks like this:

```
Month | Total AB Signups | Total SMB Signups
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In your second query the column name is also `Total AB Signups` but it is `Total SMB Signups` in the desired result; I guess this is a typo and not intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `where` condition to a `case` expression inside the count function:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from created_at),'-', extract(year from created_at)) AS "Month", 
count(case when is_accountant='t' then email end) AS "Total AB Signups",
count(case when is_accountant='f' then email end) AS "Total SMB Signups"
from users
group by 1,extract(month from created_at),extract(year from created_at)
order by extract(year from created_at),extract(month from created_at);
```

Or, if you are using Postgresql 9.4+ you can use the new `filter` syntax:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from created_at),'-', extract(year from created_at)) AS "Month", 
count(email) FILTER (where is_accountant='t') AS "Total AB Signups",
count(email) FILTER (where is_accountant='f') AS "Total SMB Signups"
from users
group by 1,extract(month from created_at),extract(year from created_at)
order by extract(year from created_at),extract(month from created_at);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was super helpful.

Comment: Btw do you mind checking out my other questions that I posted today?